# Show that a semigroup with $aS \cup \{a\} = bS \cup \{b\}$ and $Sa \cup \{a\} = Sb \cup \{b\}$ is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

Let $S$ be a semigroup such that for all $a,b \in S$
$$
 aS \cup \{a\} = bS \cup \{b\} \quad \text{and} \quad
 Sa \cup \{a\} = Sb \cup \{b\}.
$$
where $aS = \{as : s \in S \}$ and similarly $Sa$. I want to show that $S$ is a group.

The above conditions imply
$$
 a \in bS
$$
for $a \ne b$, hence $S \setminus\{b\} \subseteq bS$ for all $b \in S$. If $S$ contains an idempotent $e$, then as $e \in eS$ we have $eS = S = Se$ and $e$ is the identity. With an identity element it is easy to see that $aS = S$ and $S = Sa$ for every $a \in S$, hence that $S$ is a group.

So, if I could show that $S$ contains an idempotent then it follows that $S$ is a group. But here I am stuck, so could anyone provide a hint how to proceed?

By the way, this is an exercise from J. Howie *Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory* (page 61).

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: Before downvoting please leave a comment what I could improve (or add a comment to your downvote at least)... I dont know either why this was downvoted!

Comment: Is $S$ finite?...

Comment: @greedoid No, it could be infinite (otherwise I already know every finite semigroup has at least one idempotent).

Comment: @StefanH I am not the downvoter on this occasion, but it is pointless to ask downvoters to leave comments, because downvoting is anonymous, whereas comments are not.

Comment: @DerekHolt That being said, if the purpose of actively downvoting is, as far as I can tell, to make this site a better place, then leaving a comment is the only way to teach the poster what they can do better. So downvoting without a comment serves little purpose except possibly scare new users away from the site (which, if I'm allowed to be cynical, might be a goal to some).

Comment: I don't know much about semigroups, but i had a quick look at the book. Lemma 2.2.1 seems to say that multiplying by $s$ on the right is a bijection of $S$, and similarly on the left. So, for $a \in S$, there exists $e$ with $ae=a$, and then $ae^2=ae$, so $e^2=e$, and $e$ is an idempotent.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your afford. But Lemma 2.2.1 says its just a bijection between corresponding $\mathcal L$-classes, and not the entire semigroup $S$ (or do you see that this is implied?). Also that $ae^2 = ae$ implies $e^2 = e$ uses left-cancellability, which is not supposed here?

Comment: @DerekHolt Okay, yes by my assummption there is just one $\mathcal L$-class! So this is fine, and also by this cancellability follows.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, this seems to be the solution!

Comment: I was initially unsure how to get $e$ with $ae=b$, but that is also essentially done in lemmas in the book. If $a \ne b \in S$, then there exist $s,t \in S$ with $as=b$ and $bt=s$, so $ast=a$.

Comment: @DerekHolt You mean how to get $e$ with $ae = a$...? Btw I made your comment into a self-contained answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by DerekHolt, the key is Green's Lemma (as cited in the mentioned book on page 49). To formulate it, we start with an arbitrary semigroup $S$, and we define equivalence relations $\mathcal R$ and $\mathcal L$ on $S$ by setting
\begin{align*}
 a \mathcal R b & :\Leftrightarrow \{a\} \cup aS = \{ b \} \cup bS, \\
 a \mathcal L b & :\Leftrightarrow \{a\} \cup Sa = \{ b \} \cup Sb
\end{align*}
for all $a, b \in S$.
These are part of what is known as [Green's relations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations)
Then we have:

(**Green's Lemma**) If $a \ne b$ and $a \mathcal R b$ with $as = b, a = bt$, then the maps
$$
 x \mapsto xs
 \quad \mbox{and} \quad
 x \mapsto xt
$$
are mutually inverse bijections between the $\mathcal L$-classes of $a$ and $b$, which preserve $\mathcal R$-classes. A similar (dual) relation holds if $a\mathcal L b$.

*Proof*: Its easy to see that $\mathcal L$ is a left congruence and $\mathcal R$ is a right congruence. Hence if $x\mathcal L a$ then $xs \mathcal L as$, so $xs \mathcal L b$ because $b = as$. Similarly, right multiplication by $t$ maps the $\mathcal L$-class of $b$ into the one of $a$. So the two maps between the $\mathcal L$-classes are well-defined. Also, if $x = ua$ then
$$
 xst = uast = ubt = ua = x
$$
and similarly $yts = y$ for all $y \mathcal L b$; hence they are mutually inverse on the corresponding $\mathcal L$-classes. Also, as $\mathcal R$ is a right congruence, the images of $\mathcal R$-related elements stay $\mathcal R$-related, but further as $x = (xs)t$ for $x \mathcal L a$ we have $x \mathcal R xs$ and so the mapping stays in the same $\mathcal R$-class for all elements $\mathcal L$-equivalent to $a$. $\square$

The assumption of the question gives that we just have a single $\mathcal R$-class and a single $\mathcal L$-class. So pick arbitrary $a \ne b$ and $as = b$ and $a = bt$, then for every $x \in S$ by the above we have
$$
 xst = x 
$$
giving that $e := st$ is idempotent (set $x := e$ above) and a right-identity. Further as the equations $ux = e$ and $xu = e$ are solvable for each $u \in S$ it must be a group.

**Remark 1**: With further theory from the book it is shown that every non-empty intersection of an $\mathcal L$-class and an $\mathcal R$-class is a group.

**Remark 2**: In the paper [Intersections of maximal ideals in semigroups](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2316957?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by P. Grillet I found

> An ideal $I$ is maximal iff $S - I$ is a $\mathcal J$-class.

And the same proof works in case of right-ideals and $\mathcal R$-classes and left-ideals and $\mathcal L$-classes. So if $aS = S \setminus \{a\}$, then as $aS$ is a right ideal it is maximal and $\{a\}$ would be a single $\mathcal R$-class, which is excluded. Hence $aS = S$ for all $a \in S$. Similar $Sa = S$ for all $a \in S$ so that $S$ is a group. And the result follows without Green's lemma.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is indeed related to Green's relations. The hypothesis tells you that all the elements of your semigroup are $\mathcal{R}$-equivalent and $\mathcal{L}$-equivalent. Therefore, there are all $\mathcal{H}$-equivalent. It now suffices to apply the following standard result (see for instance [1, Proposition 1.4]).

> Let $H$ be an $\mathcal{H}$-class of a semigroup. The following
>   conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. $H$ contains an idempotent,
> 2. there exist $s$, $t \in H$ such that $st \in H$,
> 3. $H$ is a group.

[1] P.A. Grillet, Semigroups, an introduction to the structure theory, Marcel Dekker, Inc., New York, 1995